# limite presque sure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I just want to know why for a continue process X such $X_{t} \rightarrow Z$ p .s when $t \rightarrow \infty$ then lim inf $X_{s}^{2}$=Z when p .s  $t \rightarrow \infty$ inf is on  $\frac{t}{2}\leq s \leq t$. 
Thanks

Comment: what you look for is $\lim_{t\to +\infty}\inf_{\frac{t}{2}\leq s \leq t} X_s = Z$ almost surely, right?

Comment: @LiuGang excuse me as i don't knew the result i wrote it like i saw it! i know that the square was  sprising!

Answer (score 0):

This is a deterministic result: assume that $x_t\to z$ when $t\to\infty$ and that $A_t\subseteq\mathbb R$ is such that for every $t$ there exists some $s$ such that $A_u\subseteq[t,+\infty)$ for every $u\geqslant s$, then $\inf\{x_s\mid s\in A_t\}\to z$ when $t\to\infty$. (Likewise, $\sup\{x_s\mid s\in A_t\}\to z$ when $t\to\infty$.)

**Note:** Obviously, $\inf\{x_s^2\mid s\in A_t\}\to z^2$ when $t\to\infty$.

Comment: I will learn thanks a lot.